# AVAudioPlayer.play() does not play sound

Tags: macos, swift, audio, avfoundation

Why doesn't the following code play a sound? It returns "true" for play(), but I cannot hear anything.

```
    let path = "/Users/account/Music/sound.mp3";
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    var Player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:fileURL, error:nil);

    Player.delegate = self;
    Player.prepareToPlay();
    Player.volume = 1.0;
    var res = Player.play();
    println(res);
```

If I use the following code instead, I can hear the sound.

```
    var inFileURL:CFURL = fileURL!;
    var mySound = UnsafeMutablePointer<SystemSoundID>.alloc(sizeof(SystemSoundID));
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(inFileURL, mySound);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound.memory)
```

- OS X Yosemite 10.10.3
- Xcode 6.2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that `Player`, your AVAudioPlayer, is a *local variable*. So it goes out of existence immediately - before it can even start playing, let alone finish playing.

Solution: make it a *property* instead, so that it will *persist*.

Comment: And, for the crucial lifetime difference between a local (automatic) variable and a property, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_variable_scope_and_lifetime

Comment: I added  var Player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(); outside the function, and then it worked.