# Trouble with looping audio music play in viewDidLoad Swift 3

Tags: audio, swift3, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

Im trying to have music loop once the app launches. No build errors are showing but the music does not play. Here is the code I have inside of viewDidLoad. Also I imported AVFoundation and SpriteKit at the top. (The solutions that have been presented in similar questions are related to Swift 2 and do not work in Swift 3)

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
```

//Here I change the background color of the datepicker

```
    dateWheel.backgroundColor = .blue
    dateWheel.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

//Music should start playing once app launches

```
    func playSound(soundName: String)

    {
        let musicPlay = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "chinaAudioNew", ofType: "mp3")!)
        do{
            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:musicPlay as URL)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
            audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1

        }catch {
            print("Error getting the audio file")
        }
    }



    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AVAudioPlayer.play() does not play sound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379524/avaudioplayer-play-does-not-play-sound)

Comment: this is swift 3, I attempted those solutions however sound is still not playing

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:musicPlay as URL)
```

That is a *local* variable so it goes out of existence even before it ever gets a chance to start playing.

Comment: What should I put in its place ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379524/avaudioplayer-play-does-not-play-sound

Comment: I added this outside of the function however still not audio... var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer();

Comment: I do not know what you are doing now. What I know is the code you put in your question. And I assure you that my answer correctly explains why _that_ code will never play any sound.

Comment: so I should scrap the whole block or just that line? How do I make it a property so that it always exists?