# Unable to play audio from URL in Swift while making MacOS app

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, audio, avplayer

So, this must be one of the most difficult problems I've ever ran into.
All I'm trying to do is play audio in a MacOS app from a URL, using Swift and Xcode 11.4.1

I've already tried this

```
    import AVFoundation

    var player : AVPlayer
    let url = URL.init(string: "https://api.fetchdev.host/m.mp3")
    player = AVPlayer(url: url!)

    player.play()
```

and this

```
    var player : AVPlayer
    let url = URL.init(string: "https://api.fetchdev.host/m.mp3")
    player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url!)
    player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)

    player.play()
```

and this

```
let url = URL.init(string: "https://api.fetchdev.host/m.mp3")
    let playerQueue = AVQueuePlayer()
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url!)
    playerQueue.insert(playerItem, after: nil)
    playerQueue.play()
```

and this

```
let url = URL.init(string: "https://api.fetchdev.host/m.mp3")
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
    player.play()
```

and this

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode.default)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        player = try AVPlayer(url: url as URL)
        guard let player = player
            else
        {
            return
        }
        player.play()
```

(MacOS doesn't support AVAudioSession)

and this

```
let url = URL.init(string: "https://api.fetchdev.host/m.mp3")
    do{
        let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
```

(Error here is "Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)"")

and some 3rd party cocoapods ones, which I didn't like.
None of this worked.
I also have this in my info.plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict/>
</dict>
```

The most complicated part about all this is the errors I get in the console:

```
2020-09-30 23:55:16.184418+0300 PRG[11553:2581729] validateSessionInfo: bundleID is invalid. Please specify the bundleID for kRTCReportingSessionInfoClientBundleID
2020-09-30 23:55:16.185563+0300 PRG[11553:2581728] startConfigurationWithCompletionHandler: Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.rtcreportingd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.rtcreportingd}
2020-09-30 23:55:16.185686+0300 PRG[11553:2581728] startConfigurationWithCompletionHandler: Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.rtcreportingd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.rtcreportingd}
2020-09-30 23:55:16.593461+0300 PRG[11553:2569623] [] [23:55:16.593] itemasync_SetProperty signalled err=-12785 (kCMBaseObjectError_Invalidated) (owning player is invalidated) at /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-2755.10.2/Prototypes/Player/FigPlayer_Async.c:3239
2020-09-30 23:55:16.593573+0300 PRG[11553:2569623] [] [23:55:16.594] itemasync_SetProperty signalled err=-12785 (kCMBaseObjectError_Invalidated) (owning player is invalidated) at /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-2755.10.2/Prototypes/Player/FigPlayer_Async.c:3239
2020-09-30 23:55:16.593648+0300 PRG[11553:2569623] [] [23:55:16.594] itemasync_SetProperty signalled err=-12785 (kCMBaseObjectError_Invalidated) (owning player is invalidated) at /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-2755.10.2/Prototypes/Player/FigPlayer_Async.c:3239
2020-09-30 23:55:16.593787+0300 PRG[11553:2569623] [] [23:55:16.594] itemasync_SetProperty signalled err=-12785 (kCMBaseObjectError_Invalidated) (owning player is invalidated) at /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-2755.10.2/Prototypes/Player/FigPlayer_Async.c:3239
2020-09-30 23:55:16.594006+0300 PRG[11553:2569623] [] [23:55:16.594] itemasync_SetProperty signalled err=-12785 (kCMBaseObjectError_Invalidated) (owning player is invalidated) at /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-2755.10.2/Prototypes/Player/FigPlayer_Async.c:3239
2020-09-30 23:55:16.594426+0300 PRG[11553:2581735] [] [23:55:16.594] playerasync_runOneCommand signalled err=-12785 (kCMBaseObjectError_Invalidated) (invalidated) at /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-2755.10.2/Prototypes/Player/FigPlayer_Async.c:1639
2020-09-30 23:55:16.599682+0300 PRG[11553:2581717] sendMessageWithDictionary: Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.rtcreportingd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.rtcreportingd}
```

I wasn't able to look up any info about at least one error.
I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you show real code? Code doesn't just float in mid-air; everything has to be inside a function, except for instance properties. Please show actual code so we can see whether all those lines of code are in the right place. Thanks!

Comment: @matt , I’m afraid there’s simply nothing to show. Yes, code does not float in mid-air, but why would I place irrelevant information here? Anything that my script has besides this, is an IBAction, which calls a function, containing all these pieces of code. That function must start playing. If I can provide you with any further details, please, tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you knew what was irrelevant, you might not be having the issue. For example, look at your very first code. Look at that first line, `var player : AVPlayer`. I know that if it is _inside_ the IBAction function, or _inside_ any other function, playing will fail. But I don't know whether _you_ know that, so I can't assume anything about what your portrayal of your code really means.

Comment: @matt, I’m sorry about making this confusing. IBAction just calls the following function: func play(){
 <Everything from the question>}. Thanks

Comment: Well, if that's true, and `func play` truly _contains_ all the code you are showing, then you are getting exactly the expected result — no sound. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379524/avaudioplayer-play-does-not-play-sound

Comment: @matt, thank you very, very much. You’re amazing.

Answer (score 1):

So, as Matt said in comments, my problem was in making the Player variable local, instead of storing it as a property.

This was the solution: [AVAudioPlayer.play() does not play sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379524/avaudioplayer-play-does-not-play-sound)

Answer (score 0):

The following code implements an avplayer for macOS in swift.  It may be run in Xcode by adding a new file called 'main.swift' and copy/pasting the code into it.  Additionally you will need to delete the pre-existing AppDelegate to avoid duplicate symbols.

```
import Cocoa
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
var window:NSWindow!
var playerView:AVPlayerView!

@objc func openAction(_ sender:AnyObject ) {
let op = NSOpenPanel()    
    op.title                   = "Choose a file"
    op.showsResizeIndicator   = true
    op.showsHiddenFiles        = false
    op.canChooseDirectories   = true
    op.canCreateDirectories    = true
    op.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    op.allowedFileTypes        = ["aiff","mp4", "mpg"]

  if (op.runModal() == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK) {
    let player = AVPlayer(url:op.url!)
    playerView.player = player
    window.setTitleWithRepresentedFilename(op.url!.lastPathComponent)
  } else {
   return
 }
}

func buildMenu() {
 let mainMenu = NSMenu()
 NSApp.mainMenu = mainMenu
 // **** App menu **** //
 let appMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
 mainMenu.addItem(appMenuItem)
 let appMenu = NSMenu()
 appMenuItem.submenu = appMenu
 appMenu.addItem(withTitle: "Quit", action:#selector(NSApplication.terminate), keyEquivalent: "q") 
}
    
func buildWnd() {
    
let _wndW : CGFloat = 500
let _wndH : CGFloat = 400

 window = NSWindow(contentRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,_wndW,_wndH),styleMask:[.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable], backing:.buffered, defer:false)
 window.center()
 window.title = "AVPlayer"
 window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)

// **** AVPlayerView **** //
playerView = AVPlayerView(frame:NSMakeRect( 0, 60, _wndW, _wndH - 60))
playerView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]
window.contentView!.addSubview (playerView)

// **** Open Button **** //
let myBtn = NSButton (frame:NSMakeRect( 30, 10, 125, 30 ))
 myBtn.bezelStyle = .rounded
 myBtn.autoresizingMask = [.maxXMargin,.maxYMargin]
 myBtn.title = "Open file. . ."
 myBtn.action = #selector(self.openAction(_:))
 window.contentView!.addSubview (myBtn)

// **** Quit btn **** //
let quitBtn = NSButton (frame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 10, 40, 40 ))
 quitBtn.bezelStyle = .circular
 quitBtn.autoresizingMask = [.minXMargin,.maxYMargin]
 quitBtn.title = "Q"
 quitBtn.action = #selector(NSApplication.terminate)
 window.contentView!.addSubview(quitBtn)
}
 
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
 buildMenu()
 buildWnd()
}

func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
 return true
}

}
let appDelegate = AppDelegate()

// **** main.swift **** //
let app = NSApplication.shared
app.delegate = appDelegate
app.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
app.activate(ignoringOtherApps:true)
app.run()
```